# Protect from access lvm encrypted partition from windows

Tags: windows, linux, encryption, lvm

This is my first question here, so forgive me if it isn't appropriate or too noobish.

I want to install Linux and Windows on my machine, but so that the linux partitions would be lvm encrypted and protected from beeing accessed from Windows, or other "live" distributions.

Is it possible to do so? What would be the best way? Can you provide some reference to a good guide?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, do you want to access the encrypted partitions on Windows or not ( the text contradicts the title)?

Comment: @AluísioA.S.G., sorry for the confusion, I want that the partition could _not_ be accessed, or how to achieve that. I updated the title.

Answer (score 2):

If you plan to install Linux to a partition within the hard drive where Windows is installed, I suppose there is no way to "hide" it completely.

Windows will see an "unused" partition, but it won't understand it anyway (unless you'd find a driver to access ext4 filesystems from Windows (I remember seeing one, but it has only reading support)).

As to the LVM encryption, most installers have an option to encrypt the filesystem. Just check the installation guide (see [Debian Installer](http://wiki.debian.org/DebianInstaller/FAQ#Q:_How_do_I_install_using_LVM.3F_Is_there_any_more_information_about_using_the_LVM_installer.3F_LVM_installation_doesn.27t_work.21)).

Comment: I want to install Linux with LVM encryption. Then, to create a new partition (by resizing a current one), and install Windows on it. However, I couldn't resize the partition after installing Linux (I tried cfdisk and gparted). How can I do that? Also, would it be possible to access the linux data from Windows?

Comment: @gg.kaspersky You'd have to supply more info (e.g. what errors do you get?). I'd also say you should open a new thread instead of asking it here.

Comment: but, strictly speaking, if I'll manage to do that, would it be possible to access the encrypted linux partitions? Would it be secure, that's the question I ask.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky As I said, the partition is known to Windows. Windows just doesn't **know how** to read it. Even without an encryption it's pretty secure (if use use an unknown filesystem to Windows). With an encryption it would definitely be secure.

Comment: @gg.kaspersky Wouldn't it be easier to just install Windows first then resize it and config Linux using Wubi or the likes afterwards? Windows installation will wipe GRUB with Windows own boot loader.